# Problems with double array?

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing

I am required to create a program which reads in data from a .cvs file, and use these (x, y and z) values for a series of calculations.

I read  in the file as a string, and then split this into 3 smaller strings for x, y and z.

The x, y and z coordinates represents the x and y coordinates of the contours of a lake, and the depth (z).
One of the calculations which I have to do, is to calculate the surface area of the lake, using the formula `(x[i]*y[i+1])-(x[i+1]*y[i])`, where `z(depth) = 0`.

I can get my code to run perfectly, up until the `x[i+1]` and `y[i+1]`, where it keeps giving me a value of 0.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Here is my code;

```
{
    string[] ss = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:File.csv");

    for (int i = 1; i < ss.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] valuesAsString = ss[i].Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        double[] X = new double[valuesAsString.Length];
        double[] Y = new double[valuesAsString.Length];
        double[] Z = new double[valuesAsString.Length];

        for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++)
        {
            X[n] = double.Parse(valuesAsString[0]);
            Y[n] = double.Parse(valuesAsString[1]);
        }

        do
        {
            double SurfaceArea = (X[n] * Y[n + 1]) - (X[n + 1] * Y[n]);

            Console.WriteLine(SurfaceArea);
        }

        while (Z[n] == 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: does your file open properly?

Comment: Your code looks like it shouldn't even compile, given that `n` is declared in a for loop and then used outside that loop. It would also *really* help if you'd pay some attention to your formatting. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be ideal.

Comment: could you paste one line or 3 lines of what the file looks like.. there is a simpler way of creating a .csv file without having to do all of the splits / whiles and do's that you have. if I could see your example of the file I could paste some code that would save you time and headaches.. I would also using a better naming convention for your variables .. kind of sloppy in nature and could lead to much potential confusion..

Comment: @Jon, isn't `n` declared external to the loop block? It's part of the loop conditional, but outside the scope of the loop block, and within the same scope as the other references.

Comment: that being said, why even have that `n` loop there in the first place?

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis: "for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++)" looks like it's declared in the loop to me...

Comment: I'm new to C#, so I'm not quite sure why, but the program doesn't seem to run properly without the n loop.

Comment: Are you sure the code you have in the question is the same as what you are trying to run?  As Jon mentioned, this shouldn't compile because 'n' is only declared for the loop.  Also, your do-while looks look like it will run forever because Z[n] is always '0' because you never assign it to anything after the array is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, im not sure if i got it right, so you if you would take a look to what i did and tell me if its of any help.

After reviewng it a little i came up with the following:

A class for the values

```
    public class ValueXyz
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public int Z { get; set; }

    }
```

A class to manange the calculation:

```
    public class SurfaceCalculator
    {

    private ValueXyz[] _valuesXyz;
    private double _surface;
    private readonly string _textWithValues;

    public SurfaceCalculator(string textWithValues)
    {
        _textWithValues = textWithValues;
        SetValuesToCalculate();
    }

    public double Surface
    {
        get { return _surface; }
    }

    public void CalculateSurface()
    {

        for (var i = 0; i < _valuesXyz.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_valuesXyz[i].Z == 0)
                _surface = (_valuesXyz[i].X*_valuesXyz[i + 1].Y) - (_valuesXyz[i + 1].X*_valuesXyz[i].Y);
        }

    }


    private void SetValuesToCalculate()
    {
        var valuesXyz = _textWithValues.Split(' '); 


        _valuesXyz = valuesXyz.Select(item => new ValueXyz
                                                  {
                                                      X = Convert.ToDouble(item.Split(',')[0]),
                                                      Y = Convert.ToDouble(item.Split(',')[1]),
                                                      Z = Convert.ToInt32(item.Split(',')[2])
                                                  }).ToArray();

    }


}
```

So now your client code could do somethin like:

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void TestSurfaceCalculatorGetsAValue()
    {
        //var textWithValues = File.ReadAllText(@"C:File.csv");
        var textWithValues = "424.26,424.26,0 589.43,231.46,0 720.81,14.22,1";
        var calculator = new SurfaceCalculator(textWithValues);
        calculator.CalculateSurface();

        Assert.IsNotNull(calculator.Surface);
    }
```

I'm not very sure i got the idea correct of how to implement the formula, but i just wanted to expose an alternative you can use, you can never have to many ways of doing one thing :).

Cheers.

By the way part of the intent i had, was not tying up your funcionality to the csv in case your source for the text in the future would change.

Answer (score 0):

Step through your code in the debugger.  Pay special attention to tbe behavior of the line

```
        for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++)
```

This loop will execute how many times?  What will the value of n be during each iteration through the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing i noticed is when you're setting your X, Y, Z vars, you're setting it to the Length of the array object instead of it's value - is that intentional?

Put a debug break on the line with:
    double SurfaceArea = (X[n] * Y[n + 1]) - (X[n + 1] * Y[n]); 
and check the datatype of "X", "Y" and "Z"

I've had problems in the past where it tries to calculate them as strings (because it took it out of the data source as strings).  I ended up fixing it by adding CInt() to each of the variables (or Convert.ToInt32();).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As this looks like it might be a homework problem, I am trying not to give a direct solution in my answer, but I see a number of questionable parts of your code that you should examine.

1. Why are X, Y, Z arrays?  You are creating a new array each time through the outer loop, setting the length of the array to the number of elements in the line, then only assigning a value to one element of X and Y, and never assigning Z to anything.
2. As phoog suggests in his answer, what is the purpose of: `for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++)`?
3. What are you trying to accomplish with the do-while loop?  As it has been mentioned in the comments by Mr Skeet, `X[n]`, `Y[n]`, `Z[n]` don't exist because `n` does not exist outside of the loop it is declared for.  Even if it did exist `Z[n]` will always be zero because you never assign anything to the Z array after it is initialized, so the do-while loop will run forever.